# when use onerror, ontimeout properties? (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

I use XMLHttpRequest class to send payload data from web client to web server.

I want to handle errors such as follows...

- REQUEST TIMEOUT (CONNECTION TIMEOUT)
- 500, INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
- 502, BAD GATEWAY
- 503, SERVICE UNAVAILABLE

I do not know the obvious usage of onstatechange, onerror, ontimeout properties.
I do not know if onreadystatechange alone can catch those errors.

Also, if I have to use onerror, ontimeout, I want to know what is the difference with onreadystatechange.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks, @karthick..
onreadystatechange is supported on all browsers, and onerror is supproted on specific browsers. right?

Answer (score 0):

- `onreadystatechange` is the function that is triggered when the `xmlhttprequest` object state changes, similar to the `onclick`.
- `readystate` is used to catch the `xmlhttprequest` object state , it has five values listening the server response state
- status is the status code returned after the server responds successfully.
  such as 500, INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.....